# What is the Action needed for the Iron Weapon/Ancestral Weapon Revelations?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, oracle

Reading over the [Oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/) Mysteries for a future build I noticed that the [Metal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/metal/) and [Ancestor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/ancestor/) Mysteries seem to have a bit of information missing. Both the "Iron Weapon" Revelation and the "Ancestral Weapon" Revelation do not have an action specified for activating the ability/creating the weapon in question.

Given that the majority of Oracle Revelations that are offensive Supernatural (Su) abilities appear to use Standard actions, I would make the assumption that these two Revelations are also Standard actions. Is this a fair assumption? Is there an errata somewhere that specifies the action economy for these Revelations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quote from oracle, revelation ability:

> Unless otherwise noted, activating the power of a revelation is a standard action.

Furthermore, from combat, under 'using a special ability':

> Supernatural Abilities (Su)
>
> Using a supernatural ability is usually a standard action (unless defined otherwise by the ability’s description). Its use cannot be disrupted, does not require concentration, and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Therefore, using a supernatural oracle revelation is certainly a standard action, unless the ability itself explicitly states otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the info was out there, but I couldn't seem to find the specific rules text about Su abilities and Revelations anywhere.